# How to list only the dot files and dot folder names (without the content in them)

Tags: linux, shell, ls

I want to list only the files and folders that are hidden (starting with dot). When I use the command

```
ls .??*
```

I get the output

```
.gitignore

.git:
COMMIT_EDITMSG FETCH_HEAD     HEAD           ORIG_HEAD      branches       config         description    hooks          index          info           logs           objects        packed-refs    refs
```

I don't want the content in the folder. Instead I'm looking for the output which only lists the folders

```
.gitignore
.git [different color for the folders, like the normal ls]
```

Comment: Can you explain why -1 was given.. I did search for listing the dot files and found the ls.. but did not find the method without directory.. of course for people who have used it before it would be easy to find..

Answer (score 13, accepted):

try:

```
ls -d .*
```

fyi

```
   -d, --directory
          list directories themselves, not their contents
```

if your ls is not alias of other command, the output of above `ls -d .*` will output files/dirs in same line. If you want to have them each in its own line:

```
ls -d1 .*
```

if you want colored output:

```
ls -d1 --color=auto .*
```

Answer (score 2):

```
ls -d .??*
```

The `-d` switch makes ls treat directory arguments just like file arguments, and won’t list its contents, but instead show the usual output (manpage excerpt follows, thanks @fedorqui):

> list directory entries instead of contents, and do not dereference symbolic links

It combines well with `-l` and others, and will, without any further switches, default to the usual multi-column view of `ls`.

Comment: From `man ls`, `list directory entries instead of contents, and do not dereference symbolic links`